# Spatial Join Geospatial data returning empty data frame

Tags: spatial-join, geospatial-pdf

I am trying to spatial join two GeoDataFrames.

This is how the dataframes look like:

[image]

[image]

I wanted to find the points within each region, but I got back an empty data frame.

```
east_region = gdf[gdf['REGION_N']=='EAST REGION']

north_region = gdf[gdf['REGION_N']=='NORTH REGION']

central_region = gdf[gdf['REGION_N']=='CENTRAL REGION']

west_region = gdf[gdf['REGION_N']=='WEST REGION']

northeast_region = gdf[gdf['REGION_N']=='NORTH-EAST REGION']

gpd.sjoin(data_geo, east_region, op='within')
```

The CRS is the same 4326 for both GeoDataFrames and when I plotted on the maps, it is clear that there are points within the north region etc.

I coded these in Google Colab.

Answer (score 0):

The WKT geometries in your point geometries in the first dataframe suggest you are mixing up the lat and lng when you are creating those geometries. They should be `POINT(lng lat)` and it looks like you are generating `POINT(lat lng)`